# Between numbers in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I want my code echo something when `'x'` is in between `'y'` and `'z'`.

This is the original code:

```
<?php echo ($articles[$art]['stock']>1 ? "x " : "z)"); ?>
```

Comment: There is no question, stupid or not.

Comment: Your question is using ternary. It's wrong. That's not how it works.

Comment: Could you reframe your question, please?

Comment: I'm trying to make it echo 'x' when the value is between '1' - '200,000' and, make it say something else when it's '0' or above '200,000'. Sorry for the inconvience

Comment: @easyquestions no problem but edit your post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$x=1;
$y=200000;
$stock = (int)$articles[$art]['stock']; //Don't forget to cast as integer.
if ($stock>x && $stock<y)
    echo "Stock is between $x and $y";
else if ($stock == 0)
    echo "Stock is empty";
else if ($stock > $y)
    echo "Stock is above $y";
```

Comment: I think this might be it. What if I simply want a third value? Thanks

Comment: What third value?

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most basic way:

```
y < x < z
echo testRange(x, y, z) ? "is in range" : "out of range";

function testRange($int,$min,$max){
    return ($min<$int && $int<$max);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($x > 1 AND $x < 200000) {
    echo $x;
}
else {
    echo $w;
}
```

Comment: I know. .. It is a principle. Changed to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help!